# ¿Como puedo lograr que el contenido de un arraylist, se reemplace por otro? (Lo pise)

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, clase, objeto

les comento la situación y mi planteo.
Tengo 3 ArrayList, 1er puesto, 2do, y 3ro, donde adentro hay un Atleta que tiene como atributo el "tiempo".

Si yo ingreso 3 atletas, con segundos 20, 30, y 40, quisiera que se guarden cada uno en su respectivo ArrayList de 1er, 2do, y 3er puesto.
El dilema viene cuando necesito ingresar un atleta con 10 segundos. El primer puesto pasaria a ser el 2do, y el 2do pasaria a ser el 3er puesto. Pero no logro hacer que se pisen los ArrayList.

Les paso lo que escribí.
Me sucede que solo ingreso un Atleta y se guardan en los 3 ArrayList de los puestos.
Aclaro, uso ArrayList porque pueden haber más de atleta en un primer puesto (Cuando coinciden los segundos)

```
public void calcularResultados(){

        double valorMaximo1erPuesto = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double valorMaximo3erPuesto = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        if (getListaDeCorredores().size() > 0) {
            for (Atleta atleta : getListaDeCorredores()) {
                if (atleta.getSegundos() < valorMaximo1erPuesto) {
                    valorMaximo1erPuesto = atleta.getSegundos();
                    listaDe2doPuesto = listaDe1erPuesto;
                    listaDe3erPuesto = listaDe2doPuesto;
                    getListaDe1erPuesto().add(atleta);      

                }else if (atleta.getSegundos() == valorMaximo1erPuesto) {
                    getListaDe1erPuesto().add(atleta);

                }else if (atleta.getSegundos() > valorMaximo1erPuesto) {

                    if (atleta.getSegundos() < valorMaximo3erPuesto) {
                        listaDe3erPuesto = listaDe2doPuesto;
                        getListaDe2doPuesto().add(atleta);

                    }else {
                        getListaDe3erPuesto().add(atleta);
                    }
                }

            }
        }else {
            getListaDe1erPuesto().clear();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

listaDe2doPuesto no es un array list.. o si.. pero en realidad, es una referencia al arraylist.

Cuando haces

```
listaDe2doPuesto = listaDe1erPuesto;
```

No estas copiando los valores de listaDe1erPuesto a listaDe2doPuesto, si no que estas diciendo que apuntan a la misma lista.. con lo cual, al cambiar algo en listaDe1doPuesto, ahora tambien lo estas cambiando en la primera.

Tu codigo no esta del todo mal. Lo que haces sirve. hasta cierto punto.. con un poco de desorden (ordenado) lo vamos a conseguir.

este es tu codigo problematico:

```
listaDe2doPuesto = listaDe1erPuesto;
listaDe3erPuesto = listaDe2doPuesto;
getListaDe1erPuesto().add(atleta);
```

Y esto te propongo (y el orden es la clave de la cuestion):

```
//la 3, ahora apunta a donde estaba la 2. ojo que aca lo que estaba en la 3 quedo en un limbo
//cuidado con los agujeros de memoria
listaDe3erPuesto = listaDe2doPuesto;
//la 2, ahora apunta a donde estaba la 1
listaDe2doPuesto = listaDe1erPuesto;
//tenemos que hacer de la 1 algo nuevo
listaDe1doPuesto = new ArrayList(); //o como sea que lo definas
getListaDe1erPuesto().add(atleta);
```

Ahora si, tu codigo deberia funciona.